# make node's async return bluebird promise

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, global, bluebird

In Node.js v7.8.0 I have a module `foo.js`:

```
class Foo {
    async bar() { return 'bar' } 
}
```

In the main module `app.js` I assign Bluebird to the global Promise:

`global.Promise = require('bluebird')`.

And in `app.js' I have:

```
const Foo = require('./foo);
let foo = new Foo();
foo.bar().tap(res => console.log(res));
```

I assumed that since I replaced the global Promise with Bluebird, a call to an async function will return a Bluebird promise (which has `.tap`), but apparently I'm wrong, because I'm getting the error:

`TypeError: foo.bar(...).tap is not a function`

Is there a way to achieve what I desire?

Comment: You could use babel to transpile your async functions into generators wrapped in Bluebird's coroutine method: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-module-method/

Comment: @idbehold Thanks, but I prefer not use transpilers. I want to use the native implementation of async\await in Node, if that's possible.

Comment: Then you'll be using native Promises as well.

Comment: It would be like doing `global.String = MyCustomString` and expecting `'foo'` to return an instance of `MyCustomString`.